# How to sort Ember Data model output?

Tags: ember.js

I've searched and searched, but all the examples seem either outdated, aren't in the file structure enforced by Ember CLI, etc.

Anyway, say I have a model in app/models/employee.js:

`export default DS.Model.extend({
    firstname: DS.attr('string'),
    lastname: DS.attr('string'),
});`

And a route in app/routes/employees.js:

`export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() { return this.store.findAll('employee'); },
});`

And a template in app/routes/employees.hbs:

`{{#each model as |employee|}} 
      <tr><td>{{employee.firstname}}</td><td>{{employee.lastname}}</td></tr>
{{/each}}`

What do I need to add to sort that table by firstname, for example?
I gather I'm supposed to use Ember.computed.sort(), something like:

`sortedEmployee: Ember.computed.sort('employees', ['firstname'])`

And then do `{{#each sortedEmployee as ...}}` in the template, but I'm apparently not defining sortedEmployee in the right place.

Answer (score 3):

app/controllers/employees.js

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  sortProperties: ['firstname:asc'],
  sortedEmployees: Ember.computed.sort('employees', 'sortProperties')
});
```

app/routes/employees.hbs:

```
{{#each sortedEmployees as |employee|}}
  {{employee.firstname}}
{{/each}}
```

Example in JSbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/regowa/7/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track, try the following:

```
sortProperties: ['firstname:asc'],  // or just 'firstname', or 'firstname:desc'
sortedEmployee: Ember.computed.sort('employees', 'sortProperties')
```

I think it's weird to have to define an extra property on the component/controller, but that way it works.

Comment: And where does that go?  In the route?

Comment: On the component or controller!